# Common Table Expressions - is there a way to do them in MikroOrm?

Tags: mikro-orm

Is there a way (even a hacky way) to do common table expressions with MikroOrm? I've searched all over and can't even find any post mentioning it whatsoever.

Comment: You can run a raw query via `em.execute()` and map the results to entities via `em.map()`, for the root entity it should be quite easy, not so much if you want to map some relations from a single query.

Comment: Using virtual entities could be a nice way to handle the mapping as well, see https://mikro-orm.io/docs/virtual-entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CTE's with Mikro-ORM. Mikro-ORM built on top of Knex.js query builder that supports it. Here is an example:

```js
  const knex = em.getKnex();
  const result = await knex
    .with('cte_name', ['participant_id', 'sum_minutes'], (qb) =>
      qb
        .from('attendance')
        .select('participant_id', knex.raw('sum(minutes) as sum_minutes'))
        .groupBy('participant_id'),
    )
    .select('*')
    .from('cte_name')
    .orderBy('sum_minutes', 'DESC');
```

if you need to map raw results to Mikro-ORM entities, you can use `em.map()`

```js
const entities = result.map((r) => em.map(EntityType, r));
```